# Hudson CI node distribution / prebuild task in multi-configuration project

Tags: hudson, distributed, functional-testing

i'm currently setting up a small grid of hudson nodes to utilize them for distributed testing different runtime configurations of our products.

Is there a way to trigger the startup of a node when a job is invoked?

The build phase of the 'multi-configuration project' that i use already wants to run within the active node. Perhaps there is way to add a prebuild step which will be executed within the master?

The only possible solution that i can imagine is to add a upstream project that runs before the 'multi configuration' project which will start the nodes.

Greetings

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to start up a node on an as-needed basis. The easiest way is to start it up using ssh. It is fairly easy to configure. See http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds for the documentation.